# Alamofire Not Immediately Saving Image to Disk

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

This is my code:

```
let destination = DownloadRequest.suggestedDownloadDestination(for: .documentDirectory)
_ = Alamofire.download("http://www.sample.com/images/sample.png", to: destination)

let documentsDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
let userDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentsDirectory, userDomainMask, true)

if let dirPath = paths.first {
    let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("sample.png")

    if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path) {
        self.sampleImage.image = image
    }

}
```

First time I ran this code, the image was nil; so I set a breakpoint on the download, stepped just past the download code, checked the directory on disk and the image has not been saved to file (which is why the image was nil). After all the code in the `UIViewContoller` class was ran, the file was successfully saved to disk, and the second time I navigated to the ViewController, the image loaded.

Is there any way to download the image, immediately save it to disk, then display the image right after?

I've tried putting the download code in `viewWillAppear` and the load from disk code in `viewDidLoad`. I also tried creating a method with a completion block and put the download code inside the completion block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Alamofire.download function is asyncronous, so it will start the download and your code will continue to be executed immediately.

You should use the function's handler to manipulate the file as soon as it is downloaded.

```
Alamofire.download("http://www.sample.com/images/sample.png", to: destination).responseData { response in
    if let data = response.result.value {
        let documentsDirectory = FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory
        let userDomainMask = FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask
        let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(documentsDirectory, userDomainMask, true)

        if let dirPath = paths.first {
            let imageURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: dirPath).appendingPathComponent("sample.png")

            if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imageURL.path) {
                self.sampleImage.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you for you help!